# How to use list data as variable

Tags: python

I need to use list value as variable. How could it be done.

```
comp_list = [ "list1", " list2", "list3"]
for comp in comp_list:
    print (comp)
    cmd = 'ps -aef | grep $comp'<<<<
    print (cmd)
    status, command = getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

the `<<<` directing to `$comp` should be replaced by `list1` and then `list2` and it should go on.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to substitute `$comp` with value of `comp`?

Comment: `'ps -aef | grep ' + str(comp)`

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = 'ps -aef | grep $comp'<<<<
```

This could be done like this:

```
cmd = 'ps -aef | grep %s' % comp
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `str.format`:

```
cmd = 'ps -aef | grep {}'.format(comp)
```

Or just concatenate strings:

```
cmd = 'ps -aef | grep ' + comp
```